# Aggregate information using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm still trying to fully grasp working with the Stream package in Java 8 and was hoping for some help.

I have a class, described below, instances of which I receive in a list as part of a database call.

```
class VisitSummary {
    String source;
    DateTime timestamp;
    Integer errorCount;
    Integer trafficCount;
    //Other fields
}
```

To generate some possibly useful information about this, I have a class `VisitSummaryBySource` which holds the sum total of all visits (for a given timeframe):

```
class VisitSummaryBySource {
    String sourceName;
    Integer recordCount;
    Integer errorCount;
}
```

I was hoping to construct a `List<VisitSummaryBySource>` collection which as the name sounds, holds the list of `VisitSummaryBySource` objects containing the sum total of records and errors encountered, for each different source.

Is there a way I can achieve this using streams in a single operation? Or do I need to necessarily break this down into multiple operations? The best I could come up with is:

```
Map<String, Integer> recordsBySrc = data.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(VisitSummaryBySource::getSource,
                    Collectors.summingInt(VisitSummaryBySource::getRecordCount)));
```

and to calculate the errors

```
Map<String, Integer> errorsBySrc = data.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(VisitSummaryBySource::getSource,
                    Collectors.summingInt(VisitSummaryBySource::getErrorCount)));
```

and merging the two maps to come up with the list I'm looking for.

Comment: You should include the usable methods and constructors of your class instead of letting us guess them from the field. I.e your code fragments of what you have tried use method references to methods not shown in your question. Further, it’s not clear whether your original source is a `List` of `VisitSummary` or `VisitSummaryBySource`. Your code suggest the latter but then it’s not clear why you have shown us the unused class `VisitSummary`…

Comment: My apologies, I tried to make the post more concise after realizing my initial post was far too long. I'll know better than to trim code and leave important stuff out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. The uses of `Collectors.summingInt` are examples of *downstream collectors* of the outer `groupingBy` collector. This operation extracts one of the integer values from each `VisitSummaryBySource` instance in the same group, and sums them. This is essentially a reduction over integers.

The problem, as you note, is that you can extract/reduce only one of the integer values, so you have to perform a second pass to extract/reduce the other integer values.

The key is to consider reduction not over the individual integer values but over the entire `VisitSummaryBySource` object. Reduction takes a `BinaryOperator`, which takes two instances of the type in question and combines them into one. Here's how to do that, by adding a static method to `VisitSummaryBySource`:

```
static VisitSummaryBySource merge(VisitSummaryBySource a,
                                  VisitSummaryBySource b) {
    assert a.getSource().equals(b.getSource());
    return new VisitSummaryBySource(a.getSource(), 
                                    a.getRecordCount() + b.getRecordCount(),
                                    a.getErrorCount() + b.getErrorCount());
}
```

Note that we're not actually merging the source names. Since this reduction is only performed within a group, where the source names are the same, we assert that we can only merge two instances whose names are the same. We also assume the obvious constructor taking a name, record count, and error count, and call that to create the merged object, containing the sums of the counts.

Now our stream looks like this:

```
    Map<String, Optional<VisitSummaryBySource>> map =
        data.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(VisitSummaryBySource::getSource,
                                reducing(VisitSummaryBySource::merge)));
```

Note that this reduction produces map values of type `Optional<VisitSummaryBySource>`. This is somewhat odd; we'll deal with it below. We could avoid the `Optional` by using another form of the `reducing` collector that takes an identity value. This is possible but somewhat nonsensical, as there's no good value to use for the source name of the identity. (We could use something like the empty string, but we'd have to abandon our assertion that we merge only objects whose source names are equal.)

We don't really care about the map; it only needs to be kept around long enough to reduce the `VisitSummaryBySource` instances. Once that's done, we can just pull out the map values using `values()` and throw away the map.

We can also turn this back into a stream and unwrap the `Optional` by mapping them through `Optional::get`. This is safe, because a value never ends up in the map unless there's at least one member of the group.

Finally, we collect the results into a list.

The final code looks like this:

```
    List<VisitSummaryBySource> output =
        data.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(VisitSummaryBySource::getSource,
                                reducing(VisitSummaryBySource::merge)))
            .values().stream()
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for an amazing explanation!

Comment: @Qrious You're welcome! And thanks for accepting. I'm not sure I got your data model exactly right; but in any case I hope the concept of the code I showed transferred properly to your actual model.